# Search a 3rd columns by putting in two values in SQL plus

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to create a report in i want to get value from a 3rd column by matching data in 2 different columns in the same table.

```
Col1           Col2              Col3

 123        20190220           456789

 456        20180101           789526

 789        20190101           623145

101        20181231           589745
```

I have col1 records and col2 records i need an sql query to get c

Comment: What is the logic to derive column3

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You'll need to clarify exactly what you need; as its written, this question doesn't explain what your problem is or what you've tried. And explain the relationship between these columns - how are you "matching data in 2 columns"?

Comment: @WillardSolutions my problem is i want to derive column 3 by search with values from column 1 and column 2(date).  I tried this query select col1, col2, col3 from table where col1 = '123' and col2 = '20190220'; It gives me result as 456789 but i want to do it for multiple values like 2000. I cannot figure out the query for it.

Comment: @Vijiy  my problem is i want to derive column 3 by search with values from column 1 and column 2(date).  I tried this query select col1, col2, col3 from table where col1 = '123' and col2 = '20190220'; It gives me result as 456789 but i want to do it for multiple values like 2000. I cannot figure out the query for it.

Comment: This is my data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/082368/1/0     i want to get doctor_code where patient_ser and case_date match.

Comment: @Netfoxf - for the sample data in fiddle what is the input which you are giving and what is the expected output

Comment: for the given sample data patient_ser and case_date are not the same, what do you mean *patient_ser and case_date match* both column should have same values

Comment: @Vijiy select * 
FROM CASES
WHERE PATIENT_SER IN ('168524', '139016', '64685', '168585', '168740', '14507')
and CASE_DATE IN ('20180101', '20180101', '20180104', '20180104', '20180105', '20180105');

Comment: i have nearly 2000 patient_ser and case_date in csv. i want to know their doctor_code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is below what you are looking for -

```
select * FROM CASES WHERE 
(PATIENT_SER = '168524' and CASE_DATE ='20180101')
or
(PATIENT_SER = '139016' and CASE_DATE ='20180101')
or
(PATIENT_SER = '64685' and CASE_DATE ='20180104')
or
(PATIENT_SER = '168585' and CASE_DATE ='20180104')
or
(PATIENT_SER = '168740' and CASE_DATE ='20180105')
or
(PATIENT_SER = '14507' and CASE_DATE ='20180105');
```

Expected results - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/082368/6

Comment: This looks like it will work thanks @Vijiy for help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IN` with tuples:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM CASES c
WHERE (c.PATIENT_SER, c.CASE_DATE) IN (('168524', '20180101'),
                                       ('139016', '20180101'),
                                       . . .
                                      )
```